# How to make my program to wait for user to close JDialog?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to make the program go to rest and the user having to confirm his return? For now I have a timer that check if the mouse was not moving on the screen and any key was pressed in last 10 minutes.

So after showing a JDialog in the timer:

```
JDialog d = new JDialog(this, "Program stopped by AntyAFK procedure.", true );
d.setSize(300, 300);
        d.show();
```

I tried to make my program rest by making a thread go to stop until user close the JDialog, because I don't want my program to make any changes when the user is away:

```
while (new MyFrame().isVisible()) {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

But it does not work. I actually know that it is incorrect, because I stopped my main thread, but for now I don't have any hint what to do to stop it and make possible way to close a new showed JDialog to restart main thread.

Comment: All this should not be needed. It is exactly what the second (true) parameter is for: modal dialog, waits until the dialog is closed by the user. Probably you should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().stop();` ← [NEVER DO THAT.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop())  That is not the only deprecated method you’re using;  `show()` is also deprecated.  I recommend enabling all compiler warnings and properly addressing them.